# Datamapper migration for Add Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

How can I write a migration for add a column to an existing table? It is easy to do with ActiveRecord but I am confused with DataMapper, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the datamapper documentaion for [auto_upgrade](http://datamapper.org/why.html). You'll find that most simple updates to your model will be easily handled. For more complex model changes check out [dm-migrations](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations).